# Applescript to search Evernote notes

Tags: applescript, evernote

So I have a Hazel rule that says "If I see a statement from this company, do X" in this case I want X to do the following.

1. Open Evernote
2. Check to see if I have a note with the same title as the downloaded file's title.
3. If no, create a note from that file. If yes, do nothing.

So what I wrote so far is.

```
global fileNamez
tell application "Finder"
    set fileNamez to name of theFile
    tell application "Evernote"
        activate
        delay (3)
        set searchString to "\"" & fileNamez & "\""
        set matches to find notes searchString
        if (not (matches exists)) then
            display dialog "no matches"
            create note title fileNamez from file theFile
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

The problem is the searching, it does not work, and I don't know whats wrong with it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set fileNamez to name of theFile

if application "Evernote" is not running then
    launch application "Evernote"
    delay 3
end if

tell application "Evernote" to set matches to find notes fileNamez
if matches = {} then
    tell application "Evernote" to set resultNote to create note from file theFile title fileNamez
    tell application "SystemUIServer" to display dialog "no matches" buttons {"OK"}
end if
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I should probably do some more reading on apple script.